# Oracle group by and the empty resulting set

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have the following SQL problem.

Scenario:

I have two tables: Change and ChangeTicket.
There is a 1:n relationship. One Change has cero or many changeTickets.
No change means no changeTickets.
A changeTicket has a status (open/closed/...)
A changeTicket has a field representing how many minutes took this change.

A Change has a company and a month. There is at most ONE change in the month.

I have to report for a given company and for a given month the sum of minutes
a given change took.

I wrote the following SQL statement.

```
select  nvl(sum(service_req), 0) as SUM_REQ 
from Change_Ticket, Change
where Change.company_id (+) = '0' 
  and Change.month (+)='07'
  and Change.Id  (+) = Change_Ticket.Change_Id
```

This is OK.

If for the given month and the given company there are neither changes nor tickets
then I get a null value which is converted to cero usgin the NVL function.

The problem arises when I want to group the information using the status.
If I add a grup clause

```
select  Change_Ticket.status, nvl(sum(service_req), 0) as SUM_REQ 
from Change_Ticket, Change
where Change.company_id (+) = '0' 
  and Change.month (+)='07'
  and Change.Id  (+) = Change_Ticket.Change_Id 
group by Change_Ticket.status
```

then my result is the empty set. 
I understand that there is no status and then the resulting set is 
somehow consistent and then an empty resulting set is returned.

How can I avoid this problem. In this case I need to report an 
**empty status** and **cero** as the the sum.

(BTW, I've also tried putting **nvl(Change_Ticket.status, 'none')** but didn't work)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to achieve what you want you would need to do this:

```
select  Change_Ticket.status, nvl(sum(service_req), 0) as SUM_REQ 
from Change_Ticket, Change
where Change.company_id (+) = '0' 
  and Change.month (+)='07'
  and Change.Id  (+) = Change_Ticket.Change_Id 
group by Change_Ticket.status
union all
select '' as STATUS, 0 as SUM_REQ
from dual
where not exists (select null from Change_ticket)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the list of your statuses in a table called `statuses`:

```
SELECT  statuses.id, nvl(sum(service_req), 0) as SUM_REQ 
FROM    statuses
LEFT JOIN
        Change
ON      Change.company_id = '0' 
        AND Change.month = '07'
        AND Change.status = statuses.id
LEFT JOIN
        Change_Ticket
ON      Change_Ticket.Change_Id  = Change.Id
GROUP BY
        statuses.id
```

or this (only if you are using `8i`, this syntax is deprecated in higher versions):

```
SELECT  statuses.id, nvl(sum(service_req), 0) as SUM_REQ 
FROM    statuses, Change, Change_Ticket
WHERE   Change.company_id(+) = '0' 
        AND Change.month(+) = '07'
        AND Change.status(+) = statuses.id
        AND Change_Ticket.Change_Id(+)  = Change.Id
GROUP BY
        statuses.id
```

If you only want to show existing statuses or a `NULL` when no records exist, use this:

```
SELECT  statuses.id, nvl(sum(service_req), 0) as SUM_REQ 
FROM    dual
LEFT JOIN
        Change
ON      Change.company_id = '0' 
        AND Change.month = '07'
LEFT JOIN
        Change_Ticket
ON      Change_Ticket.Change_Id  = Change.Id
GROUP BY
        statuses.id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have a table statuses. I only have one column status. Anyway, I will try to follow your idea. Comments are welcome.